# Fail to parse(?) decimals with FSharpValue.MakeRecord ONLY in iOS device with Region Spanish/Colombia

Tags: ios, reflection, f#, xamarin.ios, decimal

This bug not happened on Android, IOS emulator, osx, linux. Only on iOS device, when it have a region different to US/English.

I using reflection for decode Json values, and exactly in  FSharpValue.MakeRecord the data of decimals get mangled.

Repro steps

1. Create a Single View iOS app and fill it with:

```ml
namespace test
open System
open UIKit
open Foundation
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type DocumentRow = {
    doc_id:int32
    doc_kind:string
    doc_code:string
    customer_code:string
    from_code:string option
    username:string
    createdat:DateTime
    updatedat:DateTime
    dueat:DateTime option
    signature:string option
    authorized:string option
    delivery_order:int32
    price:decimal
    cost:decimal
    tax_value:decimal
    discount_value:decimal
    sub_total:decimal
    total:decimal
    status:string
    notes:string option
    syncdata:string option
    version:int32
}

module JSON =
    let fromJSON ty (fields:Reflection.PropertyInfo array) (objs:Map<string, obj>) =
        //printfn "%A" objs
        let values = fields |> Array.map(fun f ->
            let name = f.Name.ToLower()
            if objs.ContainsKey(name) then
                let value = objs.[name] 
                value
            else
                null
        )
        printfn "%A" values
        FSharpValue.MakeRecord(ty, values)

[<Register ("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate () =
    inherit UIApplicationDelegate ()
    override val Window = null with get, set
    override this.FinishedLaunching (app, options) =
        let t = typedefof<DocumentRow>
        let fields = FSharpType.GetRecordFields t

        let data = [
            "doc_id", 1|> box
            "doc_kind", "O"|> box
            "doc_code", "ORD-3-1"|> box
            "customer_code", "70084254_32"|> box
            "from_code", null
            "username", "admin"|> box
            "createdat", DateTime.Now |> box
            "updatedat", DateTime.Now |> box
            "dueat", null
            "signature", null
            "authorized", null
            "delivery_order", 0|> box
            "price", 700M|> box
            "cost", 0M|> box
            "tax_value", 0M|> box
            "discount_value", 0M|> box
            "sub_total", 3500M|> box
            "total", 3500M|> box
            "status", "Draft"|> box
            "notes", null
            "syncdata", null
            "version", null
        ]
        let ob = Map.ofList data
        let r = JSON.fromJSON t fields ob :?> DocumentRow
        printfn "Result = %A" r
        true
```

2. Run on emulator, it print in the output windows:

```ml
{doc_id = 1;
 doc_kind = "O";
 doc_code = "ORD-3-1";
 customer_code = "70084254_32";
 from_code = None;
 username = "admin";
 createdat = 28/02/2019 6:05:13 p. m.;
 updatedat = 28/02/2019 6:05:13 p. m.;
 dueat = None;
 signature = None;
 authorized = None;
 delivery_order = 0;
 price = 700M;
 cost = 0M;
 tax_value = 0M;
 discount_value = 0M;
 sub_total = 3500M;
 total = 3500M;
 status = "Draft";
 notes = None;
 syncdata = None;
 version = 0;}
```

this is correct.

3. Run on a iOS device. I have use a iPhone 6 se, but is reproducible in many others.

It print:

```ml
{doc_id = 1;
 doc_kind = "O";
 doc_code = "ORD-3-1";
 customer_code = "70084254_32";
 from_code = None;
 username = "admin";
 createdat = 28/02/2019 6:04:12 p. m.;
 updatedat = 28/02/2019 6:04:12 p. m.;
 dueat = None;
 signature = None;
 authorized = None;
 delivery_order = 0;
 price = 12912720851596686131200M;
 cost = 0M;
 tax_value = 0M;
 discount_value = 0M;
 sub_total = 64563604257983430656000M;
 total = 64564290437145643974656M;
 status = "Draft";
 notes = None;
 syncdata = None;
 version = 0;}
```

See how all the decimal values get mangled.

Related information

iOS 12.1.4
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Mono 5.16.0.221 (2018-06/b63e5378e38) (64-bit)

P.D: Reported in https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/893

Comment: What is the question here? Also it doesn't look like the example code is complete which makes it hard to reproduce in order understand what is going wrong. Also lack input data.

Comment: How workaround the bug is the question. The example is complete, the input start at line 54, and the right output and wrong output is also provided. To see it, is only needed to run the code.